# Passing data between @RestController to @Controller using ResponseEntity in Spring

Tags: java, spring, controller

I have to pass an object from RestController to Controller using `ResponseEntity` class. First request will go to AuthRestController.class using below link...

http://localhost:8080/masters/auth/apis/status?sts=YDVB7ah%2BsTr8r4APQE0Nmw%3D%3D&hsh=BgPfV2mlRHc9XfIs6GzdOiL9%2FOhLPgGBw%2B6kEoEHgvs%3D

then after some processing, it will be redirect to another controller that is ResponseController on following link...

http://localhost:8080/masters/app/response/acknowledgement

Here I'm unable to pass Status object to ResponseController.

**AuthRestController.class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth/apis")
public class AuthRestController {

    @Autowired Environment environment;
    @Autowired UserService userService; 
    @Autowired StatusService statusService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/status", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Status> status(@RequestParam String sts, @RequestParam String hsh) {      
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();            
        Status status = new Status(0, "undefined", "any status that does not exists in the system", "something's getting wrong");

        try {           
            if (!hsh.trim().equals("") && !sts.trim().equals("")) {
                String userId = Base64Utils.decrypt(URLDecoder.decode(hsh.trim(), "UTF-8").replace(" ", "+")).split("\\-")[0].trim();
                User user = userService.getUser(Integer.parseInt(userId));
                if (user != null && user.getUserKey() != null && user.getUserKey().equals(hsh.trim())) {
                    String decrypted = Base64Utils.decrypt(URLDecoder.decode(sts.trim(), "UTF-8").replace(" ", "+"));
                    status = statusService.getStatus(Integer.parseInt(decrypted));
                    user.setStatus(status);
                    user.setUserKey(null);
                    userService.updateUser(user);                   
                }
            }           
            httpHeaders.setLocation(new URI(environment.getRequiredProperty("application.domain") 
                    + "app/response/acknowledgement"));         
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(e);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<Status>(status, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.SEE_OTHER);
    }
}
```

**ResponseController.class**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/app/response")
public class ResponseController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/acknowledgement",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String acknowledgement(ModelMap model) {     

        // How to get Status object here sent from AuthRestController?
        // To be passed in model as attribute

        model.addAttribute("msg", status.getMessage());     
        return "acknowledgement";
    }               
}
```

So, Is there any way to get Status instance in acknowledgement() method? Or anything's wrong in my approach?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a lot of effort to do what Spring Security does out of the box.